# How can I substitute various long strings for a shorter strings throughout my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to replace a long string in my dataframe with a much shorter string. I have a short dictionary of replacements I want to make.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

replacement_dict = {
    "substring1": "substring1",
    "substring2": "substring2",
    "a short substring": "substring3",
}

exampledata = StringIO("""id;Long String
1;This is a long substring1 of text that has lots of words
2;This is substring2 and also contains more text than needed
3;This is a long substring1 of text that has lots of words
4;This is substring2 and also contains more text than needed
5;This is substring2 and also contains more text than needed
6;This is substring2 and also contains more text than needed
7;Within this string is a short substring that is unique
8;This is a long substring1 of text that has lots of words
9;Within this string is a short substring that is unique
10;Within this string is a short substring that is unique
""")

df = pd.read_csv(exampledata, sep=";")
print df

for s in replacement_dict.keys():
    if df['Long String'].str.contains(s):
        df['Long String'] = replacement_dict[df['Long String'].str.contains(s)]
```

The expected dataframe would look like this:

```
   id  Long String
0   1  substring1
1   2  substring2
2   3  substring1
3   4  substring2
4   5  substring2
5   6  substring2
6   7  substring3
7   8  substring1
8   9  substring3
9  10  substring3
```

When I run the code, above, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    if df['Long String'].str.contains(s):
  File "h:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 731, in __nonzero__.format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I substitute various long strings for a shorter strings throughout my dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this type of thing with [`.replace()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html). However, you will have to modify your dictionary slightly to get the result you expect.

```
replacement_dict = {
    ".*substring1.*": "substring1",
    ".*substring2.*": "substring2",
    ".*a short substring.*": "substring3",
}
```

What I did what make the keys a regex string. It will match everything before and everything after the substring you want to match. This will be important in a minute.

Next, replace your entire `for` loop, with the following:

```
df['Long String'] = df['Long String'].replace(replacement_dict, regex=True)
```

`.replace()` can take a dictionary where the keys are the strings you are matching and the values are the replacement text. The reason for changing the keys to capture everything before and after your substring is because we can now replace the entire value, instead of just a small matched string.

For example, the dictionary without the `.*` portion would convert to a dataframe like so:

```
   id                                        Long String
0   1  This is a long substring1 of text that has lot...
1   2  This is substring2 and also contains more text...
2   3  This is a long substring1 of text that has lot...
3   4  This is substring2 and also contains more text...
4   5  This is substring2 and also contains more text...
5   6  This is substring2 and also contains more text...
6   7    Within this string is substring3 that is unique
7   8  This is a long substring1 of text that has lot...
8   9    Within this string is substring3 that is unique
9  10    Within this string is substring3 that is unique
```

Notice that the only change you really see is with the "a short substring" values, because you are really just replacing "substring1" and "substring2" with itself.

Now, if we add the regex wildcards back, we get this:

```
   id Long String
0   1  substring1
1   2  substring2
2   3  substring1
3   4  substring2
4   5  substring2
5   6  substring2
6   7  substring3
7   8  substring1
8   9  substring3
9  10  substring3
```